# Dynamically export graphs in phpspreadsheet library

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have a page with a lot of checkboxes (+- 40), each of them represent a graph the user can export to Excel (I use the phpspreadsheet library for this).

Some graphs will be line graphs with 1 line, others will have multiple lines, there will be pie charts, lists, ... all kinds of graphs and data.

It is important to note that my export worksheet will contain different sheets, one per category which will contain only graphs. And 1 "data" tab, which will contain the raw data for each graph that is exported in a single tab (regardless of category).

I am stuck with the point in where I dynamically define my labels and data for each graph exported. Since I do not want a lot of white space (eg. when I hardcode each graph his own place in the Excel sheet, and the user decides to only export the last graph, I want it to be displayed most left, rather than completely at the end with a lot of white space before).

I decided to pre-define ranges upfront with a fixed column span, so that I can accommodate the smallest, but also the largest datasets in these graphs, because some will have 2 columns, but other will have 4 or 5 columns. (it's not ideal but I'm not sure how to make the ranges also dynamic).

I will explain with code example:

I have 2 variables defined that indicate the ranges for everything.

```
    //Graphs are placed on category sheets, so we don't need more than 8 graphs per sheet
        $graphColumns = [
             'A2:H15', 'J2:Q15', 'A17:H30',
             'J17:Q30', 'S2:Z15', 'AB2:AI15',
             'S17:Z30', 'AB17:AI30'
        ];
        //All raw data for each graph (+- 40 now) will be exported to the raw data sheet
        $dataColumns = [
             'A3', 'G3', 'M3', 'S3', 'Y3', 'AE3', 'AK3', 'AQ3',
             'AW3', 'BC3', 'BI3', 'BO3', 'BU3', 'CA3', 'CG3', 'CM3',
             'CS3', 'CY3', 'DE3', 'DK3', 'DQ3', 'DW3', 'EC3', 'EI3',
             'EO3', 'EU3', 'FA3', 'FG3', 'FM3', 'FS3', 'FY3', 'GE3'
        ];
```

At this point I create all the sheets (one for each category and one for the raw data).

I then call a function for each graph to be exported, like so:

```
drawAmountNewVacancies($vacanciesSheet, $rawDataSheet, $result, array_shift($graphColumns), array_shift($dataColumns));
```

The `$vacanciesSheet` contains a reference to the sheet where the graph needs to be inserted, `$rawDataSheet` contains a reference to the sheet where I want to insert the raw data, `$result` is the result from my database query (contains the raw data that I want to insert), and then I take the first element of the `graphColumns` and `dataColumns` arrays, and make sure it cannot be used by another function call anymore, since array_shift removes them.

For this specific graph, I know I will have 2 columns, one containing the dates and one containing the total amounts.

So I create a multidimensional array, and insert it in position `array_shift($dataColumns)` (A3 in this example), like so:

```
$rawDataArray = [];
    $rawDataArray[0][0] = '';
    $rawDataArray[0][1] = 'Totaal';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($queryResult as $res) {
        $rawDataArray[$i][0] = $res->date;
        $rawDataArray[$i][1] = (int)$res->total_amount;
        $i++;
    }

    $datasheet->fromArray(
        $rawDataArray,
        '',
        $dataColumn
    );
```

This inserts the data fine as I want it, at this point, in order to make a line graph, I need to define `dataSeriesLabels`, `xAxisTickValues` and `dataSeriesValues`.

**This is the point where I am stuck.**

In order to create the graph, I need to define a couple of variables like so:

```
$dataSeriesLabels = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Ruwe data!$B$3', null, 1)
    ];
    $xAxisTickValues = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Vacatures!$A$3:$A$55', null, 4)
    ];
    $dataSeriesValues = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Vacatures!$B$3:$B$55', null, 4)
    ];
```

How do I tell the library where to look for the data? Since I only have a starting point (A3) determined upfront (and insert it with `fromArray`), I have no context of my B column (and potentially, C,D, etc)